# Assigning IPv4 Address from ifaddrs Structure to sockaddr_in Structure

Tags: c++, c, sockets, vxworks

I'm developing a UDP Server application.
I wish to bind my server socket to a particular interface (read from configuration file). In this case `eth0`.
I'm using `getifaddrs` to read all information about present network interfaces.
I then iterate over the linked list as returned `getifaddrs` and check the name of each interface against the interface I want. 
Once a match is found I plan extract the IPv4 address from `struct ifaddrs` and assign it to `struct sockaddr_in` object.
Currently I'm unsure on how I can pass `struct ifaddrs->ifa_addr->sa_data` to `struct sockaddr_in.sin_addr.s_addr` or is it the right/recommended approach I'm following.

Code :

```
bool start_server(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in  server_address;
    struct ifaddrs      *ifaddr;
    int                 return_value;
    try
    {
        this->sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if (this->sock_fd < 0) 
        {
            //TODO : Log Error
            return false;
        }

        // Initialize and configure struct sockaddr_in server_address
        std::memset(&server_address, sizeof(sockaddr_in), 0); // Initialize struct sockaddr_in server_address to 0
        server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_address.sin_port = htons(6666); //We are using the port 6666

        //Get IP address from the interface (eth0 currently) -> Interface name to be read from the configuration file
        return_value = getifaddrs(&ifaddr);
        if (return_value < 0) //On error, -1 is returned
        {
            //TODO : Log Error
            return false;
        }
        for (struct ifaddrs *ifa; ifa != nullptr; ifa = ifaddr->ifa_next)//ifa stand for interface address
        {
            if (std::strcmp(ifa->ifa_name, "eth0") == 0) //We check the interface name in the linked Strings are exact match
            {
                if (ifa->ifa_addr == nullptr)
                {
                    //TODO : Log Error - Selected interface doesn't have an assoiciated IP address
                    break; 
                }
                else
                {
                    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ifa->ifa_addr->sa_data); //I am unsure will this work or if this is the right approach
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        freeifaddrs(ifaddr); //Free up memeory allocated by getifaddrs. Prevents Memory Leaks
}
```

Comment: This doesn't looks like C

Comment: `C` and `C++` are different and distinct languages.  Tags need to be edited.

Comment: you forgot to initialize ifa in your loop

Comment: I'd argue that the C tag should stay, as the question is about a C API.

Comment: @GauravPathak ryyker The reason for C-tag is because the system call API in question is based in C.

Comment: The API may be based in C, but the code in question is clearly C++ (there is no `this->` or `std::` in C).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ifa_addr` member is a pointer to a `struct sockaddr`.  First, you want to make sure it's for an IPv4 address by checking if `sa_family` is set to `AF_INET`, and if so you can use `memcpy` to copy it to a `struct sockadr_in`.

```
    for (struct ifaddrs *ifa = ifaddr; ifa != nullptr; ifa = ifaddr->ifa_next)
    {
        if (std::strcmp(ifa->ifa_name, "eth0") == 0)
        {
            if (ifa->ifa_addr == nullptr)
            {
                //TODO : Log Error - 
                //Selected interface doesn't have an assoiciated IP address
                break; 
            }
            else if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
            {
                memcpy(&server_address.sin_addr, ifa->ifa_addr, 
                       sizeof(server_address.sin_addr));
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```